# Remove part of a string

Tags: r, regex, string

How do I remove part of a string?  For example in `ATGAS_1121` I want to remove everything before `_`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Use regular expressions.  In this case, you can use `gsub`:

```
gsub("^.*?_","_","ATGAS_1121")
[1] "_1121"
```

This regular expression matches the beginning of the string (^), any character (.) repeated zero or more times (*), and underscore (_).  The ? makes the match "lazy" so that it only matches are far as the first underscore.  That match is replaced with just an underscore.  See `?regex` for more details and references

Comment: Previous regex would match to the last underscore in the case of, e.g., `gsub("^.*_","_","ATGAS_1121_xxx")`.  Now fixed.

Comment: @Joshua I find it really useful that you explained the role of the regular expressions.

Comment: This also works with a vector of strings as the last argument. R is awesome like that.

Answer (score 46):

You can use a built-in for this, ***strsplit***:

```
> s = "TGAS_1121"
> s1 = unlist(strsplit(s, split='_', fixed=TRUE))[2]
> s1    
 [1] "1121"
```

*strsplit* returns *both* pieces of the string parsed on the *split* parameter as a *list*. That's probably not what you want, so wrap the call in *unlist*, then *index* that array so that only the second of the two elements in the vector are returned.

Finally, the *fixed* parameter should be set to TRUE to indicate that the split parameter is not a regular expression, but a literal matching character.

Answer (score 33):

If you're a Tidyverse kind of person, here's the [stringr](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/) solution:

```
R> library(stringr)
R> strings = c("TGAS_1121", "MGAS_1432", "ATGAS_1121") 
R> strings %>% str_replace(".*_", "_")
[1] "_1121" "_1432" "_1121"
# Or:
R> strings %>% str_replace("^[A-Z]*", "")
[1] "_1121" "_1432" "_1121"
```

Answer (score 25):

Here's the `strsplit` solution if `s` is a vector:

```
> s <- c("TGAS_1121", "MGAS_1432")
> s1 <- sapply(strsplit(s, split='_', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
> s1
[1] "1121" "1432"
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! FYI to get the first part of the string (i.e. before the '_'), replace the [2] on the end with a [1].

Comment: @verbamour do you know how to modify this to keep the first 2 elements of the string

Comment: @d3hero23 I believe @stevenjoe answered that above.
Applying his solution gives you
`s1 <- sapply(strsplit(s, split='_', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[1]))`

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the most intuitive solution is probably to use the `stringr` function `str_remove` which is even easier than `str_replace` as it has only 1 argument instead of 2.

The only tricky part in your example is that you want to keep the underscore but its possible: You must match the regular expression until it finds the specified string pattern `(?=pattern)`.

See example:

```
strings = c("TGAS_1121", "MGAS_1432", "ATGAS_1121")
strings %>% stringr::str_remove(".+?(?=_)")

[1] "_1121" "_1432" "_1121"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the `strsplit` solution for a dataframe using `dplyr` package

```
col1 = c("TGAS_1121", "MGAS_1432", "ATGAS_1121") 
col2 = c("T", "M", "A") 
df = data.frame(col1, col2)
df
        col1 col2
1  TGAS_1121    T
2  MGAS_1432    M
3 ATGAS_1121    A

df<-mutate(df,col1=as.character(col1))
df2<-mutate(df,col1=sapply(strsplit(df$col1, split='_', fixed=TRUE),function(x) (x[2])))
df2

  col1 col2
1 1121    T
2 1432    M
3 1121    A
```