# Erase minutes and seconds from character dates in R

Tags: r

I have this timestamp vector:

```
c("01/09/2019 9:51:03", "01/09/2019 9:51:39", "01/09/2019 9:57:04", 
"01/09/2019 10:01:41", "01/09/2019 10:06:06", "01/09/2019 10:09:36", 
"01/09/2019 10:11:55", "01/09/2019 10:21:15", "01/09/2019 10:21:39", 
"01/09/2019 10:52:20")
```

I'd like to strip off the minutes and seconds from the character vector so that I just have `01/09/2019 9` and `01/09/2019 10`

What is the most efficient method to do so?

Comment: Interesting accepted answer, what is your definition of efficient?

Comment: I'm pretty biased towards `tidyverse` packages :)

Comment: ah I see, I don’t blame you :) next time you should probably put it in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
date_strings <- c("01/09/2019 9:51:03", "01/09/2019 9:51:39", "01/09/2019 9:57:04", 
"01/09/2019 10:01:41", "01/09/2019 10:06:06", "01/09/2019 10:09:36", 
"01/09/2019 10:11:55", "01/09/2019 10:21:15", "01/09/2019 10:21:39", 
"01/09/2019 10:52:20")

str_extract(date_strings, ".+(?=:.+:)")

 [1] "01/09/2019 9"  "01/09/2019 9"  "01/09/2019 9"  "01/09/2019 10"
 [5] "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10"
 [9] "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one.

```
datevec <- c("01/09/2019 9:51:03", "01/09/2019 9:51:39", "01/09/2019 9:57:04", 
      "01/09/2019 10:01:41", "01/09/2019 10:06:06", "01/09/2019 10:09:36", 
      "01/09/2019 10:11:55", "01/09/2019 10:21:15", "01/09/2019 10:21:39", 
      "01/09/2019 10:52:20")

format(as.POSIXct(datevec, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS"), "%d/%m/%Y %H")

# Result
 [1] "01/09/2019 09" "01/09/2019 09" "01/09/2019 09" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10"
 [7] "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10"
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your desired output class? How about this one:

```
v <- c("01/09/2019 9:51:03", "01/09/2019 9:51:39", "01/09/2019 9:57:04", 
  "01/09/2019 10:01:41", "01/09/2019 10:06:06", "01/09/2019 10:09:36", 
  "01/09/2019 10:11:55", "01/09/2019 10:21:15", "01/09/2019 10:21:39", 
  "01/09/2019 10:52:20")


strptime(v, "%m/%d/%Y %H")
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems nice,

```
unlist(strsplit(mystring, split = ":", fixed=TRUE))[c(TRUE, FALSE,FALSE)]
```

(Made with help from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410206/in-r-split-a-character-vector-by-a-specific-character-save-3rd-piece-in-new-ve))

Alternative could be,

```
sapply(strsplit(mystring, split=':', fixed=TRUE), `[`, 1)
```

Using some benchmarks and recent comments by Ronak, that fixed=TRUE makes the methods a lot faster, we see that method **four** (the above method) is fastest,

```
mystring <- c("01/09/2019 9:51:03", "01/09/2019 9:51:39", "01/09/2019 9:57:04", 
              "01/09/2019 10:01:41", "01/09/2019 10:06:06", "01/09/2019 10:09:36", 
              "01/09/2019 10:11:55", "01/09/2019 10:21:15", "01/09/2019 10:21:39", 
              "01/09/2019 10:52:20")

microbenchmark(one = sapply(strsplit(mystring, split=':', fixed=TRUE), `[`, 1),
           two = unlist(lapply(mystring,function(x) strsplit(x,":", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1])),
           three = strptime(mystring, "%m/%d/%Y %H"),
           four = unlist(strsplit(mystring, split = ":", fixed=TRUE))[c(TRUE, FALSE,FALSE)],
           five = format(as.POSIXct(mystring, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS"), "%d/%m/%Y %H"), 
           six = gsub("(.*?):.*", "\\1", mystring),
           seven = str_extract(mystring, ".+(?=:.+:)"),
           times = 100000)



    Unit: microseconds
  expr     min      lq      mean  median       uq        max neval
   one  42.792  49.471  85.63742  52.572  57.1310  669280.96 1e+05
   two  64.637  70.618 114.16364  73.252  77.6840  582466.94 1e+05
 three 129.456 134.771 156.82308 136.188 139.2030  339715.94 1e+05
  four  12.860  15.641  22.75699  17.254  18.5440  305703.52 1e+05
  five 482.888 505.647 633.15388 512.880 552.1155  551274.28 1e+05
   six  37.889  43.121  52.79030  45.567  49.1880   32954.59 1e+05
 seven  53.432  59.051  88.05015  62.326  69.9320 1180361.17 1e+05
```

Comment: yep. I think `fixed = TRUE` makes it a lot faster.

Comment: Very interesting, actually 4, with fixed=TRUE is fastest, changed the benchmark to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
dates <- c("01/09/2019 9:51:03", "01/09/2019 9:51:39", "01/09/2019 9:57:04", 
                  "01/09/2019 10:01:41", "01/09/2019 10:06:06", "01/09/2019 10:09:36", 
                  "01/09/2019 10:11:55", "01/09/2019 10:21:15", "01/09/2019 10:21:39", 
                  "01/09/2019 10:52:20")
unlist(lapply(dates,function(x) strsplit(x,":")[[1]][1]))
```

gives

```
 [1] "01/09/2019 9"  "01/09/2019 9"  "01/09/2019 9"  "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10"
 [6] "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10" "01/09/2019 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one using `gsub`

Capture the pattern by `()` and `\\1` to refer to the captured group, need `?`to make regex lazy as there are multiple `:`.

```
gsub("(.*?):.*", "\\1", dates)
```