# Could someone please explain these gsub arguments precisely?

Tags: regex, r

I have this code for trucating strings after an underscore "_" is found, but I don't understand the operators/arguments that were passed through gsub to make this manipulation possible. In particular, why I should have to gsub "\\1" instead of "". I do note that the output of gsubbing nothing removes the entire string. I am also a bit confused by how the operators are being used, particularly parantheses and brackets:

```
AAA <- "ATGAS_1121"
(aa <- gsub("([^_]*).*", "\\1", AAA))
## [1] "ATGAS"
```

Please note, this post draws heavily from: [R remove part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704213/r-remove-part-of-string)

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: [`"([^_]*).*"`](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5B%5E_%5D*%29.*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regex `(..)` called capturing group which captures all the characters matched by the pattern present inside that group. You could refer those characters by back-referencing the group index number.

```
gsub("([^_]*).*", "\\1", AAA)
```

`([^_]*)` captures all the characters at the start but not of `_` zero or more times. Following `.*` matches all the remaining characters. `gsub` will replace all the matched characters with the chars in the replacement part. If your code is like,

```
gsub("([^_]*).*", "", AAA)
```

it would remove all the characters, since we matched all the characters but captured only those characters(*not of `_` symbol*) which are present at the start. So by replacing the matched characters with the chars present inside the group index 1, will give you the part before `_` symbol.

You could achieve the same result using `\K`

```
> gsub("[^_]*\\K.*", "", AAA, perl = TRUE)
[1] "ATGAS"
```

Since `\K` is a PCRE feature, you must need to enable `perl=TRUE` parameter. `\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

Comment: Or you could just do `gsub("_.*", "", AAA)`

Comment: i think `sub` would be enough for all.

Answer (score 2):

**Why I should have to gsub `\\1` instead of `""`**

A [**back-reference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) tells the engine to match the characters that were captured by a capturing group. A capturing group can be created by placing the characters to be grouped inside a set of parenthesis, `( ... )`. Every set of capturing parentheses from left to right gets assigned a number, whether or not the engine uses these parentheses when it evaluates the match.

In this case you need to use the back-reference `\1` inside of the replacement call to assign the characters that were matched by Group 1 into the new string `aa`. By using `""` instead, you're assigning `aa` an empty value since the regular expression pattern matches the entire string.

**I am also a bit confused by how the operators are being used ... brackets**

The square brackets `[ ... ]` you're asking about are called a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which defines a set of characters. Saying — "match **one** of the characters specified by the class".

**How I would recommend doing this:**

In this example, a regular expression is not needed at all, you can simply split the string.

```
AAA <- 'ATGAS_1121'
strsplit(AAA, '_', fixed=T)[[1]][1]
# [1] "ATGAS"
```

And if you insist on using regular expression, you can use `sub` as follows instead:

```
AAA <- 'ATGAS_1121'
sub('_.*', '', AAA)
# [1] "ATGAS"
```