# r remove character before space in a string

Tags: r, string, split, strsplit

I have a column within a dataframe where some values are like this

```
   Col1
   Y 183.21
   500.23

   432.89
   Y 428.29


   Y500
```

I am looking for a way to remove only those Y prior to those strings that have Y and some characters separated by a space ( `Y 183.21`, `Y 428.29` ) . Not the Y that is not separated by the space (`Y500`) but only Ys that are separated by space ( `Y 183.21`, `Y 428.29` ). The expected output would be

```
   Col1
   183.21
   500.23

   432.89
   428.29


   Y500
```

I tried some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704213/r-remove-part-of-string) but unsuccessful. Any advice or tips are much appricated.

Comment: It looks like you have two variables in one. I'd extract the `Y`s into a new column (maybe `grepl('Y\\d', df$Col1)`), and parse to an actual number with `readr::parse_number(df$Col1)`. Or you could get creative with `tidyr::separate` and lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use package `stringi`

```
library(stringi)

new.df<-stri_replace_all(df,"" ,fixed = "Y " )
```

Comment: Great use of `stri_replace_all` Plus one

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` assuming you have only one match

```
sub("Y ", "", df$Col1)

#[1] "183.21" "500.23" "432.89" "428.29" "Y500"
```